# Why does my SQL query give error 1146 looking for Database.Database?

Tags: mysql, sql

Why does the following statement return an 1146 error with SQL Table "HistoryDB.HistoryDB" does not exist? I am attempting to join two tables within the same database where their ids match. I apologize if the column/table names are confusing they have been mangled for security purposes.

```
select Reporttbl.id, TableInfo_tbl.lastTime
    from HistoryDB
    INNER JOIN Reporttbl AS TableInfo_tbl on Reporttbl.statID = TableInfo_tbl.statID
    WHERE lastReportTime BETWEEN '2016-09-13 00:00:00' and '2016-09-13 23:00:00'
    Group BY id, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(lastReportTime) DIV 3600 ORDER BY id ASC
```

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
select Reporttbl.id, TableInfo_tbl.lastTime
        ^^^^^^^
    INNER JOIN Reporttbl AS TableInfo_tbl etc...
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Once you alias a table, you can no longer use the "original" table name, only the alias.

Comment: I think the next problem in this query will be the `inner join`

Answer (score 0):

You are using an alias for Reporttbl  as TableInfo_tbl

so why you are using the original tablename and the alias in on clause for join  ?

could be you mean   HistoryDB

```
INNER JOIN Reporttbl AS TableInfo_tbl on Reporttbl.statID = HistoryDB.statID
```

or if the HistoryDB   is the name of the database you should call the proper table in your from clause  eg: Your_table_name

```
select Reporttbl.id, TableInfo_tbl.lastTime
from  Your_table_name
INNER JOIN Reporttbl AS TableInfo_tbl on Your_table_name.statID = TableInfo_tbl.statID
WHERE lastReportTime BETWEEN '2016-09-13 00:00:00' and '2016-09-13 23:00:00'
Group BY id, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(lastReportTime) DIV 3600 ORDER BY id ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

You're incorrectly specifying the Database name in the `FROM` clause when this should instead be your first table's name.

```
SELECT Reporttbl.id, TableInfo_tbl.lastTime
FROM TableInfo_tbl
INNER JOIN Reporttbl on Reporttbl.statID = TableInfo_tbl.statID
WHERE lastReportTime BETWEEN '2016-09-13 00:00:00' and '2016-09-13 23:00:00'
Group BY id, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(lastReportTime) DIV 3600 ORDER BY id ASC
```

You also don't need to alias `Reporttbl` in the join as you can just keep the original table name.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include HistoryDB in your ON statement and also be consistent when using an alias, or just remove it. Try the query like this:

```
SELECT Reporttbl.id, Reporttb1.lastTime
    FROM HistoryDB
    INNER JOIN Reporttbl
    ON HistoryDB.statID = Reporttbl.statID
    WHERE lastReportTime 
    BETWEEN '2016-09-13 00:00:00' and '2016-09-13 23:00:00'
    Group BY id, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(lastReportTime) DIV 3600 
    ORDER BY id ASC
```